# Text boxes not retaining values

Tags: vba, ms-access

new to the forums.

I have a problem with a database I'm designing that will log when preventative maintenance is done on a printer. Everything works up to the point where I try to move values over to another form. What I'm trying to do is take 2 values from text boxes on 1 form and move them to another form. I can get those values saved to global variables(was the only way I could get this to work) and I can get the values from the global variables in the 2nd form and they will display in the text boxes like I want. My issue is when I close the form or close the database, the global variables lose their values so I've tried to get the text boxes to save values using the .defaultvalue and .value property but it doesn't work. Here's my code that displays the global variables in the text boxes:

```
    Private Sub Form_load()

'Variables for this form

'301

Dim date301Jan As Date
Dim date301Apr As Date
Dim date301Jul As Date
Dim date301Oct As Date
Dim data301TechJan As String


'Converting global variables to the text boxes in this form
date301Jan = var301Jan
date301Apr = var301Apr
date301Jul = var301Jul
date301Oct = var301Oct
data301TechJan = var301TechJan

Me.txt301Jan = date301Jan
Me.txt301Apr = date301Apr
Me.txt301Jul = date301Jul
Me.txt301Oct = date301Oct
Me.txt301TechJan = data301TechJan



End Sub
```

This works but the values in the text boxes aren't saved. I've tried other means to save values and they don't work. I've tried a hidden form and even a table to get the values from but there's limits on the tables and my form can't pull from multiple tables...I calculated it out that I'd need well over the 255 limit. I'll attach a pic of my "end game" form as well. I'd like to setup this form so once it's full, it'll prompt the user to save it and then clear everything to start over again. Nevermind on the pic, i'm not authorized to post images yet.

Anyway, I'll try to describe the pic as best I can. I have a form that has multiple machines on it with 8 text boxes and 4 labels per machine. The labels are the months the PM is due. 4 text boxes are for the quarter(dates) the PM was done and the other 4 are for the tech that was responsible for completing the PM. There are 64 machines total so the form is pretty big.

I have searched multiple forums and I saw 1 that said change the "end sub" to "exit sub" and see if that works and it didn't. The debugger says something like "expected end sub." I haven't coded the rest of the machines because I can't get this to save.

Any input how to solve my problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, so question 1 - why are we trying to store values in the controls on the form(s)? You know youre working with a database, right? Meaning that those values could be stored in a table then recalled on form open? Just seems like sooooooo much extra work from my POV. Another thing - you dont need global values to get this done  - you can reference form controls from other forms and even move values around that way. I think because youre new to this that maybe we dont have a full grasp of the options available to you

Comment: I haven't done anything with VBA in 20 years so i'm pretty much a newbie at this. I've tried passing values through form controls and it wasn't doing what I wanted it to do. The table has a limit of 255 columns and I need around 500 so using a table is out. I'm thinking of changing the text boxes to labels and just changing the caption so the text is there even if the database is closed and reopened.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that labels will work. I used my "form1" and opened "form2" in design view and hidden and put vba code to edit the caption of the labels and then saved "form2." I closed and opened "form2" and the captions were saved like I want. I can get rid of my global variables since I no longer need them. Here's what "form1" looks like:

```
Private Sub Push_Click()
'Variable for date if PM was completed outside of required completion month

Dim newdate As Date
Dim newTech As String


'When Push is clicked, adds all values to the Log Table

    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Log([GE Printer], [Date Completed], [Report Type], [Pre 12mW], [Pre 25mW], [Pre 38mW], [Pre 50mW], [Pre 75mW], [Pre 100mW], [Pre 150mW], [Pre 200mW], [Post 12mW], [Post 25mW], [Post 38mW], [Post 50mW], [Post 75mW], [Post 100mW], [Post 150mW], [Post 200mW], [X Notch Freq], [X Gain], [X FF], [X VFF], [Y Notch Freq], [Y Gain], [Y FF], [Y VFF], [Encoder Cal], [Laser SN], [Laser Head SN], [Install HRS], [Current HRS], [Warranty HRS], [Blade Gap], [Blade Gap Offset], Threshold, [Laser RFID], [Cart RFID], [VAT RFID], [Old X Beamsize], [New X Beamsize], [Old Y Beamsize], [New Y Beamsize], ADC, Notes, [Laser Focus], Technician, [Total Laser HRS], [Printer SN]) " & _
               " VALUES(" & Me.GE_ & ",'" & Me.txtDate & "','" & Me.txtReport & "','" & Me.Pre12 & "','" & Me.Pre25 & "','" & Me.Pre38 & "','" & Me.Pre50 & "','" & Me.Pre75 & "','" & Me.Pre100 & "','" & _
               Me.Pre150 & "','" & Me.Pre200 & "','" & Me.Post12 & "','" & Me.Post25 & "','" & Me.Post38 & "','" & Me.Post50 & "','" & Me.Post75 & "','" & Me.Post100 & "','" & Me.Post150 & "','" & _
               Me.Post200 & "','" & Me.XNotch & "','" & Me.XGain & "','" & Me.XFF & "','" & Me.XVFF & "','" & Me.YNotch & "','" & Me.YGain & "','" & Me.YFF & "','" & Me.YVFF & "','" & Me.Encoder & "','" & _
               Me.SN & "','" & Me.HeadSN & "','" & Me.Install & "','" & Me.Current & "','" & Me.Warranty & "','" & Me.PhyGap & "','" & Me.Offset & "','" & Me.Threshold & "','" & Me.Laser & "','" & _
               Me.Cart & "','" & Me.Vat & "','" & Me.BeforeX & "','" & Me.AfterX & "','" & Me.BeforeY & "','" & Me.AfterY & "','" & Me.ADC & "','" & Me.Notes & "','" & Me.Focus & "','" & Me.Tech & "','" & _
               Me.Total & "','" & Me.Asset_ & "')"

newTech = CStr(Me.Tech)
DoCmd.OpenForm "PMsch", acDesign, , , , acHidden

'Applies info to the PMSch form

    '301

    If Me.GE_ = "301" Then
        If DatePart("m", Me.txtDate) = 1 Then
            Forms("PMsch")("lbl301Jan").Caption = Me.txtDate
            Forms("PMsch")("lbl301TechJan").Caption = newTech
        ElseIf DatePart("m", Me.txtDate) = 4 Then
            Forms("PMsch")("lbl301Apr").Caption = Me.txtDate
            Forms("PMsch")("lbl301TechApr").Caption = newTech
        ElseIf DatePart("m", Me.txtDate) = 7 Then
            Forms("PMsch")("lbl301Jul").Caption = Me.txtDate
            Forms("PMsch")("lbl301TechJul").Caption = newTech
        ElseIf DatePart("m", Me.txtDate) = 10 Then
            Forms("PMsch")("lbl301Oct").Caption = Me.txtDate
            Forms("PMsch")("lbl301TechOct").Caption = newTech
        Else
            newdate = InputBox("Please input Date as m/d/yyyy.")
            If DatePart("m", newdate) = 12 Or 2 Then
                Forms("PMsch")("lbl301Jan").Caption = newdate
                Forms("PMsch")("lbl301TechJan").Caption = newTech
            ElseIf DatePart("m", newdate) = 3 Or 5 Then
                Forms("PMsch")("lbl301Apr").Caption = newdate
                Forms("PMsch")("lbl301TechApr").Caption = newTech
            ElseIf DatePart("m", newdate) = 6 Or 8 Then
                Forms("PMsch")("lbl301Jul").Caption = newdate
                Forms("PMsch")("lbl301TechJul").Caption = newTech
            ElseIf DatePart("m", newdate) = 9 Or 11 Then
                Forms("PMsch")("lbl301Oct").Caption = newdate
                Forms("PMsch")("lbl301TechOct").Caption = newTech
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

Now I just need to finish coding everything else and get ready to test it with the other techs. The docmd to close/save is at the very bottom of the last printer so it's not shown in my code.

Comment: Read on [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/) and [database normalization](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/283878/description-of-the-database-normalization-basics)!

Comment: I mean Im glad you figured it out but what youre doing is very much a hack. Learn the things I suggested above (google will get you there very quickly actually). Best to learn while you have sandbox time.